# Cloud infrastructure for home and personal experimentation?

Tags: cloud-computing, web-applications

As with many techies-- I've accumulated a number of older x86 servers, x86 desktops, and Cisco switches over the last few years.

I'd like to build a small cloud cluster for web app experiments (web server + database + application server).  That is, I'm not looking to necessarily scale an entire O.S. environment.

What are my software options for building a small-scale, personal, app cloud?

Comment: "Fog computing", maybe? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered [Eucalyptus](http://open.eucalyptus.com/)? It's free and is pretty simple to set up on a couple boxes you may have. From their site:

> EUCALYPTUS - Elastic Utility Computing
>   Architecture for Linking Your Programs
>   To Useful Systems - is an open-source
>   software infrastructure for
>   implementing "cloud computing" on
>   clusters. The current interface to
>   EUCALYPTUS is compatible with Amazon's
>   EC2 interface, but the infrastructure
>   is designed to support multiple
>   client-side interfaces. EUCALYPTUS is
>   implemented using commonly available
>   Linux tools and basic Web-service
>   technologies making it easy to install
>   and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you don't need cloud computing, just cluster computing. Cloud computing involves timesharing a cluster, and these are 100 percent yours! There's projects like Hadoop to build a google mapreduce cluster, but maybe to get started you should check out [BashReduce](http://blog.last.fm/2009/04/06/mapreduce-bash-script), which mimics Hadoop with much lighter dependencies.